# How to expose mariadb out side the pod and remote excess

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

Able to acess mariadb inside the pod in node itself.

While trying to establish a remote connection it's throwing error as "Access denied root@x.x.x.x using password yes" even grant all previliage is there to the host with root user

Any thing missing?

Comment: If possible, post your yaml file and let me know where you are deploying it (AWS, GCP...)

Answer (score 1):

Set mariadb service type to NodePort or LoadBalancer

Comment: It was with clusterip, I tried with loadbalancer. Let me try with this nodeport